# Create and return a new component on-click in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components `Class` and `Students`. The `Class` component renders and returns a list of Classes in `<li>`. I want to add click events to display the Students for each Class in `Class` component.

I have the following in the render method of the Class component:

```
    render(){
        const renderClasses = () => 
            this.props.classes.map(class => {
                return (
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">{class.name}</a>
                     //class object also has a property of 'students'
                    </li>
                )
        })

        return(
            <div>
                { renderClasses() }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I want to be able to click on the anchor tags and display the corresponding students for that class. Of course the Student component should receive a prop as follows:

`<Students students={this.class.students} />`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a component `state` to save the `class` `index` that should show its students, and then add an `onClick` handler on the anchor to change that `index`.

Try the code below:

```
export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {activeClassIndex : -1}
        this.setActiveClassIndex = this.setActiveClassIndex.bind(this);
    }

    setActiveClassIndex(index){
        this.setState({
            activeClassIndex : index
        })
    }


     render(){
        const renderClasses = () =>
            this.props.classes.map( ( currentClass , index ) => {
            return (
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onClick={ () => { this.setActiveClassIndex(index) } }>{currentClass.name}</a>
                    {this.state.activeClassIndex == index ? <Students students={currentClass.students} /> : "" }
                </li>
            )
        })

        return(
            <div>
                { renderClasses() }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!